# PHP Show Array same Key wth multiple Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I need to get the content when the array same Key
I'm using `array_intersect_key` to get the same key and it returns this result:

```
Array1 :
(
[NewYork] = "5,NewYork";
[london] = "20,london";
[Pari] = "40,Pari";
)

Array2 :
(
[China] = "14,China";
[london] = "40,london";
[Tokyo] = "2,Tokyo";
)
```

**Result**

`array_intersect_key(Array1,Array2);` it return :  `[london] = "20,london";`

But I need to show `[london] = "20,london"; and [london] = "40,london";`

or something like this `[london] = "20,london|40,london";`

Without a loop I have a large file

Thank you!

Comment: You can do this: $res=array_intersect_key($arr1,$arr2); foreach($result as $k=>$v) { $final[$k] = $arr1[$k] ."|".$arr2[$k]; }. $final will be your result.

Comment: yes but i have more than 90000 line it take many time but with array_intersect_key it faster but is return only one result

Comment: Then it will take time.

Comment: Use $result instead of $res like  $result = array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2); foreach($result as $k=>$v) { $final[$k] = $arr1[$k] ."|".$arr2[$k]; }

Comment: @FaisalRehman  , yes it work thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have tried this code to get the closest result without loop. This might help you.

### **Code**

```
$array1['NewYork'] = "5,NewYork";
$array1['london'] = "20,london";
$array1['Tokyo'] = "40,Pari";


$array2['China'] = "14,China";
$array2['london'] = "40,london";
$array2['Tokyo'] = "2,Tokyo";


$res1 = array_intersect_key($array1,$array2);
$res2 = array_intersect_key($array2,$array1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_merge_recursive($res1,$res2));
die;
```

### **Result**

```
Array
(
    [london] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20,london
            [1] => 40,london
        )

    [Tokyo] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40,Pari
            [1] => 2,Tokyo
        )

)
```

Let me know if it works. Good Luck.

### **Update**

How about this? It will return the same result.

```
function myfunction($a,$b)
{
if ($a!=$b)
  {
  return 0;
  }
  return ($a>$b)?1:-1;
}
$array1['NewYork'] = "5,NewYork";
$array1['london'] = "20,london";
$array1['Tokyo'] = "40,Pari";


$array2['China'] = "14,China";
$array2['london'] = "40,london";
$array2['Tokyo'] = "2,Tokyo";

$res1 = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
$res2 = array_uintersect_assoc($res1,$array1,"myfunction");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res2);
die;
```

Comment: yes it work thank you , but We do the process twice that mean it take X2